# Looping through data and displaying only last set of items in Angular

Tags: angular

From the API I am fetching the list of categories with name and ID and then inside this list of categories I integrate the list of lectures from the second ID. This list of lectures must be different for every category (based on ID)

In my console.log() it works fine, but on the frontend I am somehow overwriting the allLectures array so that is the reason why in the frontend I get displayed only the lectures for the last category.

This lectures must be different for every category.

Typescript code:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.getCategories();   
  }


  getCategories() {
    this.categoryListSubs = this.categoryService
      .getAllCategories(this.limit, this.offset)
      .subscribe((categories: any) => {
        this.allDataFromApi = categories;
        this.categoryList = categories.results;
        this.isLoaded = true;

          this.categoryList.forEach((el: any) => {
          this.categoryID = el.id;
          this.getLectures(this.categoryID);
        });
      });
  }

  getLectures(id: any): void {
    console.log(id);

    this.isLoaded = false;

    this.allLecturesOfCategorySubs = this.categoryService
      .getLecturesOfCategory(id, this.limit, this.offset, this.queryParams.sort)
      .subscribe((allLectures: AllLecture) => {
        this.allLectures = allLectures.results;
        console.log(this.allLectures);

        this.isLoaded = true;
      });
  }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="container mb-3 pt-5">
  <div class="categories" *ngFor="let category of categoryList">
    <div class="">
      <div class="d-flex mt-4 category-button py-1">
        <h2>
          {{ category.name }} <span>({{ category.lectures }})</span>
        </h2>
        <a
          class="btn rounded-full"
          [routerLink]="['/all-lectures']"
          [queryParams]="{ page: '1', sort: 'popularity' }"
        >
          All lectures <fa-icon [icon]="faArrowRight"></fa-icon>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="videos">
        <div class="grid-4">
          <div *ngFor="let lecture of allLectures">
            <app-video-item
              [latestLecturesList]="lecture"
            ></app-video-item>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks to everyone who will try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the how you're managing your `allLectures` variable. Either convert it to a map or object to store mapping of `id` to the `result`, or, concatenate to the existing `allLectures` so that it doesn't override the previous result with new API call data.

```
// In your component, declare these variables:

allLecturesMap = new Map();

ngOnInit(): void {
      this.getCategories();   
  }


  getCategories() {
    this.categoryListSubs = this.categoryService
      .getAllCategories(this.limit, this.offset)
      .subscribe((categories: any) => {
        this.allDataFromApi = categories;
        this.categoryList = categories.results;
        this.isLoaded = true;

          this.categoryList.forEach((el: any) => {
          this.categoryID = el.id;
          this.getLectures(this.categoryID);
        });
      });
  }

  getLectures(id: any): void {
    console.log(id);

    this.isLoaded = false;

    this.allLecturesOfCategorySubs = this.categoryService
      .getLecturesOfCategory(id, this.limit, this.offset, this.queryParams.sort)
      .subscribe((allLectures: AllLecture) => {
        // either use a map
        this.allLecturesMap.set(id, allLectures.results);
        // or concatenate 
        this.allLectures = [...(this.allLectures ?? []), ...allLectures.results]; // assuming its array
        console.log(this.allLectures);

        this.isLoaded = true;
      });
  }
}
```

If you choose to use Map or Object, you need to change your HTML code to iterate through it.

```
// considering Map
<div *ngFor="let item of allLecturesMap.entries()">
    <ng-container *ngFor"let lecture of item[1]"> 
     <app-video-item
         [latestLecturesList]="lecture"
     ></app-video-item>
    </ng-container>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `getLectures` per `categoryID` and you overwrite the result with `this.allLectures = allLectures.results;` in `getLectures`.

Try modifing it to `this.allLectures.push(...allLectures.results);`.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. It is the same

Comment: In console log the displayed lectures are same, but in front end it doesn't even display lectures